# Using TextArea in TabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane, jtextcomponent

i have added a JTabbedPane with a JPanel in each tab. and a JText area within each JPanel.
the tabs can be dynamically created in the same template.

There is also a menu bar with a menu. it has options to replace an occurance of a string (eg replace "<" with "<") it worked perfectly when i just used a JPanel and textArea.

Now that i hav added the tabbedPane,... i dont know how to replace the content of the active tab alone,..

i have tried getting the selected component(getSelectedComponent() method and getComponentAt() method) and replacing the text,.. i didnt work

can some one help me

Comment: Please post [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 8):

`getSelectedIndex()` and `getSelectedComponent()` should work. Check out [How to Use Tabbed Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html) tutorial, it has good examples.

EDIT: demo of `getSelectedComponent` and `AbstractAction`

```
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class TabbedPaneDemo {

    static class TextDemoPanel extends JPanel{
        private JTextArea textArea;

        public TextDemoPanel(String text){
            textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);
            textArea.setText(text);
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);

            add(scrollPane);
        }

        public JTextArea getTextArea() {
            return textArea;
        }
    }

    static class SetTextAction extends AbstractAction {
        private JTabbedPane tabbedPane;

        public SetTextAction(JTabbedPane tabbedPane){
            super("Set text");
            this.tabbedPane = tabbedPane;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String value = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(tabbedPane, "Text", "New text");
            if (value != null){
                TextDemoPanel panel = (TextDemoPanel)tabbedPane.getSelectedComponent();
                if (panel != null)
                    panel.getTextArea().setText(value);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TabbedPaneDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

        tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 1", new TextDemoPanel("Tab 1 text"));
        tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 2", new TextDemoPanel("Tab 2 text"));
        tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 3", new TextDemoPanel("Tab 3 text"));

        frame.add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("Menu");
        menuBar.add(menu);
        JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem(new SetTextAction(tabbedPane));

        menu.add(item);

        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Also consider [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) to encapsulate the functionality.

Comment: getSelectedComponent will return the top level component of the tab. In this excellent demo, that would be the JScrollPane.  You're then going have to extract he JTextArea from it yourself

Comment: @MadProgrammer in the code above it actually returns `TextDemoPanel`.

Comment: @Max Sorry, you're absolutely right - 3 month baby just woke us up for there early morning feed :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer no worries, hope you get back to sleep soon :)